# how to create Login Activity When multiple users Access there own data

Tags: android

I am developing an App which is hostel management app 
that have login activity consist of username,password login button , and create account , when the users click on create account they can create account and then can login.but if any one create account he can access the same as the last user access. so i want to hide data from new users. what i do. I am using sqlite database in my app...
I am not asking about php and mysql i am asking about sqlite which is pure android app not online 
                      **OR**

Can u till me to create only one account mean only one account will be created in create account activity and will login through that account ,.No other account will be created

Comment: You need php Mysql to acheive login functionality...sqlite data is stored internally to the device

Comment: You ever heard of unique key in database ? based on the userid and password.. which will bring up data only which was saved against those.

Comment: read about `AccountManager` class

Comment: @kgandroid Saying "You need php Mysql to acheive login functionality" is like saying "you need C++ to write for-loops"

Comment: What I meant to say is storing the user credentials in a backend or a server.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't performed enough search on [google](http://www.google.com).
Following are few examples which will help you achieve what you want.
1. [tutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_login_screen.htm)
2. [learn2crack](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html)

You will have to combine what you learn in these both sites are create your app accordingly.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I did not ask about php and mysql i am asking about sqlite which is pure android app not online Can u till me to create only one account mean only one account will be created in create account activity and will login through that account ,.No other account will be created